# SSL (https) Refuses to load website in IPv6 network Digitalocean

Tags: ssl, https, ipv6, digital-ocean

SSH files (https://) not working in ipv6 enabled droplet.

We using Comodo PositiveSSL files. Once we remove the ssl files it's works fine with http://

Error that shows in website is,

This site can’t be reached www.website.com refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated and DO community support not able to cover this much technical info so please I appreciate your feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with your SSL , the port on which your site is running on HTTPS is not opened on the network , and may be that's causing the issue . Try the same website on HTTPS from a normal internet connection (That means outside your work network, if you are inside a one ) and if it works ,then you need to open the port on which your site is running on HTTPS . Or if you are sure that your port is accessible, then try to clear browser cache and retry . Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Well I think you made a good point @codechat but I'm not sure how to open this port for IPv6 and where the file is located on, However as you said I tested the site IPv4 and https:// and that works fine.

And this is how my current listens on a TCP or UDP port for netstat -tuplen
https://app.box.com/s/56b63lsvmcnb9e2bs7u72h890pno1rpo

Comment: Opening a port requires a person in your organization who holds network administration. So try to contact how can you get that port opened . Once it gets done over IPv6 , you're all set . Kindly accept and vote up my answer also please if it helped you :) . So that other folks can also take benefit out of it .

Comment: Sure let me try this with a network admin and will mark it as resolved, Sure already voted you. Will keep you posted with the results @codechat

Comment: Ok !  will wait for the results , Oh you voted ! but cannot it didn't reflected till now though . Anyways hope it resolves your issue :)